# mysql query error in select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying the following code and want to get value from table2 or table3, the status1 value may or may not be blank(empty) and wont get the results.

It's showing results from table2 only and not from table3.

if i remove "a.status1 LIKE b.status1" then it works fine. status1 is empty in all tables.

```
SELECT a.regno, 
a.status1, 
Coalesce(CASE 
          WHEN altervalue IS NOT NULL THEN altervalue 
          ELSE mastervalue 
        end, 0) AS value1 
FROM   table1 a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT reg_no, total1+total2 AS altervalue 
          FROM   table2) AS i 
      ON `a`.`regno` LIKE `i`.`reg_no` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT regno, total1+total2 AS mastervalue, 
                 status1 
          FROM   table3) AS b 
      ON a.status1 LIKE b.status1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using wildchar  so you could use `=` instead of `like`

```
SELECT 
  a.regno, 
  a.status1, 
  Coalesce(CASE 
          WHEN altervalue IS NOT NULL THEN altervalue 
          ELSE mastervalue 
        end, 0) AS value1 
FROM   table1 a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT reg_no, total1+total2 AS altervalue 
          FROM   table2) AS i  ON `a`.`regno` =  `i`.`reg_no` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT regno, total1+total2 AS mastervalue, 
                 status1 
          FROM   table3) AS b  ON a.status1 =  b.status1
```

or null safe comparison

```
SELECT 
  a.regno, 
  a.status1, 
  Coalesce(CASE 
          WHEN altervalue IS NOT NULL THEN altervalue 
          ELSE mastervalue 
        end, 0) AS value1 
FROM   table1 a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT reg_no, total1+total2 AS altervalue 
          FROM   table2) AS i  ON `a`.`regno` =  `i`.`reg_no` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT regno, total1+total2 AS mastervalue, 
                 status1 
          FROM   table3) AS b  ON a.status1 <=>  b.status1
```

Comment: i implemented both = and <=> buts not working. currently a.status1 and b.status1 are black(empty)

Answer (score 0):

First, simplify your query:

```
SELECT t1.regno, t1.status1, 
       COALESCE(t2.total1 + t2.total2, t3.total1 + t3.total2, 0) as value1
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.regno = t2.regno LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t1.status1 = t3.status1 ;
```

I think your final `join` is missing the condition on `regno`:

```
SELECT t1.regno, t1.status1, 
       COALESCE(t2.total1 + t2.total2, t3.total1 + t3.total2, 0) as value1
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.regno = t2.regno LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t3.regno = t1.regno AND t3.status1 = t1.status1 ;
```

I'm not sure what logic your really (you have no sample data/results).  You might want the `COALESCE()` in the other order:

```
       COALESCE(t3.total1 + t3.total2, t2.total1 + t2.total2, 0) as value1
```

Comment: @saiyesh. . . Do  you have wildcards in your columns?